# Karaf settings.xml

Tags: settings, apache-karaf

Currently we are using Apache Karaf v4.2.8 installed / running as a windows service.

We use AWS code artefact as our mvn repository, the issue here is that tokens only last for 12hrs meaning every time we need to use a new token we need to restart the windows service / karaf in order it to pick up the token and authenticate correctly (only an issue if we need to install a new feature)

Am I missing something here? is there a way to use an environment variable or something?

Answer (score 1):

Karaf contains `maven` feature you can install to manage your Maven repositories:

```
karaf@root()> feature:install maven
```

For example:

```
karaf@root()> maven:repository-list

== Remote repositories
ID                              │ URL
────────────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
central                         │ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
apache                          │ https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/
ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy │ https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots/

== Default repositories
ID                      │ URL
────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────
system.repository       │ file:/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/system/
kar.repository          │ file:/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/kar/
child.system.repository │ file:/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/system/
```

You can change configuration of any remote maven repository using `maven:repository-change` command.

By default, your Maven Master password (see `mvn -emp`) is taken from `~/.m2/settings-security.xml`, but if you invoke `maven:password -emp -p` you can set new master password and underneath Karaf will create new `settings-security.xml` and point your `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` to this file. For example:

```
karaf@root()> maven:password -emp -p
Maven security settings will be stored in new file. This file will be used in org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.security property. Continue? (y/N) y
Master password to encrypt: ********
Encrypted master password: {xxx}
New security settings stored in "/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-security-settings-1651245247562.xml"
```

`maven-security-settings-1651245247562.xml` looks like this:

```
$ cat /data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-security-settings-1651245247562.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{xxx}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

And `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` contains TWO new properties:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings = /data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-settings-1651244980542.xml
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.security = /data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-security-settings-1651245247562.xml
```

The 2nd one contains your new master password and the first one is a copy of your existing `~/.m2/settings.xml`

You can change a repository password using:

```
karaf@root()> maven:repository-change -id central --username test --password test
Maven settings will be updated and org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings property will change. Continue? (y/N) y
New settings stored in "/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-settings-1651245438306.xml"
```

`maven-settings-1651245438306.xml` was created and Maven Central now looks like this:

```
<server>
  <username>test</username>
  <password>test</password>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
```

You can also use encrypted password. First obtain it:

```
karaf@root()> maven:password -ep
Password to encrypt: ****
Encrypted password: {xxx}
You can use this encrypted password when defining repositories and proxies
```

And use it:

```
karaf@root()> maven:repository-change -id central --username test --password '{xxx}'
Maven settings will be updated and org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings property will change. Continue? (y/N) y
New settings stored in "/data/servers/apache-karaf-4.3.6/data/cache/bundle52/data/maven-settings-1651245586888.xml"
```

Thanks to master password created earlier, everything is fine:

```
karaf@root()> maven:repository-list -x

== Remote repositories
ID                              │ URL                                                            │ Username │ Password
────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────
central                         │ https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/                                │ test     │ test
```

and `maven-settings-1651245586888.xml` contains:

```
<server>
  <username>test</username>
  <password>{xxx}</password>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
```

These commands simply operate on Configuration Admin and `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn` PID. But they give you transparent handling of `settings.xml` underneath.

See documentation about Karaf Maven commands here: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_maven_configuration_commands